# How can i modify the opacity only for the task manager in Kubuntu 20.04?

Tags: kubuntu, transparency

In Kubuntu 20.04 i would like to change the opacity of the task manager. I saw some answers to this problem on Ask Ubuntu but i would like the opacity to be modify only in task manager.

From the `Widgets` download `Panel Transparency Button`. This widget modify the Task Manager to 0% opacity.

It is possible to modify the widget to show 50% opacity ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to modify the widget. Reply from the author of the widget.

[image]